# Find Time Complexity of Function where the recursive call is in a for loop

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

Here is my function:

```
function a(n)

     print 'a'
     if n == 0:
        return 
     for (int i = 0; i<=n-1; i++):
        a(i)
     return
```

So basically I understand that for each call, we're also calling all the function numbers leading to n recursively and then for each function we do the same thing again. My main problem, however, is that the for loop leaps up to a variable number every time, so it's like doing recursion inside of recursion.

Comment: I hope there's a type, and you mean `i <= n - 1`

Comment: Yes, I've revised it

Comment: The complexity is O(2 ^ n). You can always compile and understand. https://ideone.com/kcoxcd

Answer (score 2):

Does it terminate in the first place?

For `n == 0`, it just returns. But for `n == 1`, it'll call itself for `n == 0`, `n == 1` and `n == 2`. Thus calling `a(1)` will cause another call of `a(1)`...

IOW this is an endless loop and will show an infinite complexity.

---

Now after the change of the algorithm it will terminate. So let me investigate it anew.

For `n == 1` it'll only call itself with `n == 0`.

For `n == 2` it'll call itself for `n == 0`, `n == 1` and another `n == 0` due to the `n == 1`; that makes 3 calls.

For `n == 3` it'll call itself 3 times + 3 times + 1 time, makes 7 times.

For `n == 4` it'll call itself 4 times + 7 times + 3 times + 1 time, makes 15 times.

This looks very much like O(2^n - 1) = O(2^n).

(It's easy to prove by induction; The number of calls will be 2^n - 1, which is obviously true for all examples above. Given it is true for some n, it'll easily follow that it's true for n + 1)

---

Since the proof by induction isn't obvious for the OP, here it is:

First of all, since apart from the loop nothing really happens within the function, it'll only add a constant number of operations per iteration, which means it'll be sufficient to count the calls to itself.

By the above, it is proved for `n = 1`.

Now assume it has been proved for some `n`. We'll now follow it is true for `n + 1`.

By the induction hypothesis the number of calls for `a(n + 1) = n + 1 + \sum_{i=0}^n (2^i - 1)` (sorry for the notation; it would have worked on mathexchange. It states "the sum for i going from 0 up to n of (2^i - 1)").

Now `n + 1 + \sum_{i=0}^n (2^i - 1) = \sum_{i=0}^n (2^i) = 2^{n + 1} - 1` which had to be shown.

This proves that the complexity is O(2^n).

Comment: I apologize, the for loop meant to say n-1, I've edited it as such

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you'd start proving this via induction. Are these examples enough? If I end up getting a(n) = n + a(n-1) + a(n-2) + a(n-3) + ... + 1, how do I know what the values for a(n-1), a(n-2), etc. are to try and prove that this is equal to 2^n - 1?

Answer (score 0):

Analysis by @Ronald is absolutely right.

Here is a different version of the program to get a count for how many times recursion is happening for different values of `n`

```
public class FindingRec
{

   static int count;

   static void rr(int n)
   {
      count++;
      // System.out.print(n + ", ");
      if (n == 0)
         return;

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
         rr(i);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
      {
         count = 0;
         rr(n);
         System.out.println("For n = " + n + ", Count: " + count);
      }
   }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
For n = 0, Count: 1
For n = 1, Count: 2
For n = 2, Count: 4
For n = 3, Count: 8
For n = 4, Count: 16
For n = 5, Count: 32
For n = 6, Count: 64
For n = 7, Count: 128
For n = 8, Count: 256
For n = 9, Count: 512
```

**So, the complexity is exactly O(2^n).**